# What is the use of prefetch parameter in Flux.groupBy()?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

While I am using Flux.groupBy() it is hanging as it only supports 256 groups, If I want to increase prefetch value dynamically based on the requests count

1. Can it impact number of threads count?/It only just increases queue size?
2. If it only increases queue size Then how does it solve the cardinality issue?
3. If we form dynamic prefetch value shall we need to add any buffer to that?

Could some one please help me?

I was able to generate dynamic value for prefetch like

```
.groupBy(Person::getId,Math.toIntExact(count))

But it still hangs, so I added buffer(32) like below, then it was working fine, But i didn't understand the exact behavior of prefetch. Can some one please explain?
```

.groupBy(Person::getId,::getKeyUniversalEntity,Math.addExact(Math.toIntExact(count),XS_BUFFER_SIZE))

Answer (score 0):

> The prefetch amount is important as it is the amount of uncompleted items it can process. In your case, first 255 Scheduler.createWorker() calls are made, each item is put on a Worker, and then put it and the created GroupedFlux in groupBy's internal queues waiting for the Worker to complete. When the 256th item appears before any Worker completes, it is unable to put it in the queues, and hangs.

as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73989703/4467550